# git avoid to push binaries

Tags: git, binaries

Suppose I have a private repository and a public one. I develop using my private
repository, and at significant steps I do a commit in which I save all, sources]
and binaries. The reason for saving binaries is to allow to recover a previously
committed version without having then to rebuild all binaries.
When I have completed the development of a feature, I push it to a public repository,
one that is accessed by an integrator, that takes my contributes and other developers'
as well, and integrates all of them.
After having pulled all the contributed, the integrator always rebuilds the binaries.
Therefore, there is no need for me to push binaries from my private repository to
the public one, and for him to pull them.
Is there a way in git to avoid to push and pull binaries in this workflow?

Answer (score 1):

What the Fedora project does is to have a look-aside cache, in which binaries are checked in and identified by their checksums -- if you don't need the binaries, simply ignore the file that list the checksums and corresponding file names

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have two repositories, your source respository and your binary repository. Clone the source repository as a submodule of your binary repository so that you can associate a particular source revision with your binaries.

Comment: I am not an expert of submodules, but does them impose a specific structure on the work directory, i.e. their files must be kept in a subdirectory?

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that your build system uses separate source and object directories. I was thinking that it could perhaps build directly into the working directory for your binary repository, or you might be able to trivially copy the output there.

Comment: With java keeping source files and class files in separate directories is no so simple.

Comment: You could try using the `-d` parameter to `javac` to change the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

In short, name the directory with binaries in:

```
.gitignore
```

Comment: This is not a solution because .gitignore acts only on untracked files. But declaring binary files as untracked means not to save them when doing commits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you exactly want is possible.  You want 2 remote repos, but push binaries to one of them and never the other.  I do not think that will be possible without resorting to using special commands (with options to ignore .gitignore files when making a commit) for the repo to push binaries.

Take a look at the .gitignore feature to ignore files from commits (and therefore pushes).  But this isn't exactly what you want since it will stop all binaries from being pushed.

Beware checking in binaries to git as all checkouts will update the timestamp of the binary (which can be newer than the other files in your project and therefore incremental builds do not rebuilt things, since many tools use file timestamps to work out what to rebuild).

The problem for you is that in order to push anything you must commit it.  But both repos will see all commits for the branch they share and distribute.

So the only work around for you is to create a new branch in your local working copy (and in your private repo) and this branch will only have commits of the binaries.  But this is much work and headache for you to sort out and implement.

i.e. youi need to setup a workflow to switch branchs to this binary only branch, then search for all binaries, then produce a commit (possibly ignoring .gitignore or editing), then push to private repo, then undo any changes made to repo (recover old .gitgnore if you edited it), then switch back to original branch containing only source code.

My advice would be to reconsider why you need to push binaries.  Does your project rebuild take many minutes/hours ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try building the binaries in a separate directory. Then you can treat is as another local repository and keep your source repository clean from binaries. Having them in your local repository and avoid pushing specific files to the remote repository would defeat the purpose of a DVCS.